# Hue shade colours

Tags: color

Looking at the plot below, how can I know what colours made the `Hue` shade?

```
Plot3D[Cos[x - y + x], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

I want to have only the RGB or HTML color values used by `Hue`.

I have copied the colors from rm -rf♦'s answer:

```
FF0000
FF9800
CCFF00
33FF00
00FF66
00FFFF
0066FF
CB00FE
FF0099
FF0000
```

but with an imprecise tool; how can I have the correct colors used by *Mathematica*, when I use the `ColorFunction -> Hue` command?

Comment: you want to use `Blend`

Comment: Could you explain the second part of your question a bit more? Note that you don't use Mathematica syntax there.

Answer (score 7):

The old package `` Graphics`Colors` `` had the function `HSBColor[]`, which is exactly what was used before `Hue[]` became built-in. Here's a slightly tweaked reimplementation of `HSBColor[]`:

```
hue[h_?NumericQ, s_: 1, b_: 1] /; 0 <= s <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 :=
    Module[{mh = 6 Mod[h, 1], i, f, p, q, t},
           {i, f} = Through[{IntegerPart, FractionalPart}[mh]];
           {p, q, t} = b (1 - s {1, f, 1 - f});
           RGBColor @@ {{b, t, p}, {q, b, p}, {p, b, t},
                        {p, q, b}, {t, p, b}, {b, p, q}}[[i + 1]]]
```

Compare:

```
Table[hue[h], {h, 0, 1, 1/6}]
   {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 1],
    RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[1, 0, 1], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}

Table[ColorConvert[Hue[h], "RGB"], {h, 0, 1, 1/6}]
   {RGBColor[1., 0., 0.], RGBColor[1., 1., 0.], RGBColor[0., 1., 0.], RGBColor[0., 1., 1.],
    RGBColor[0., 0., 1.], RGBColor[1., 0., 1.], RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]}
```

As further confirmation, you can try doing an RGB component plot for `hue[]`, just like in Sjoerd's answer.

---

**Added 1/15/2017**

A much more compact implementation of `hue[]` (adapted from [this demo](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsS3Wc) by Quilez) goes like this:

```
hue[h_?NumericQ, s_: 1, b_: 1] /; 0 <= s <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 :=
    Apply[RGBColor, b (1 + s (Clip[Abs[Mod[6 h + {0, 4, 2}, 6] - 3] - 1, {0, 1}] - 1))]
```

---

It seems your question was altogether different (you really should try writing more clearly); here's a routine to produce hex values from a corresponding color:

```
colorToHex[col_] :=
     StringJoin["#", IntegerString[Round[255 (List @@ ColorConvert[col, "RGB"])], 16, 2]]
```

To verify that this works, let's reproduce the hex values of the named browser-supported HTML colors:

```
cols = Take[First[ColorData["HTML", "Range"]], 7]
   {"AliceBlue", "AntiqueWhite", "Aqua", "Aquamarine", "Azure", "Beige", "Bisque"}

colRGB = ColorData["HTML"] /@ cols
   {RGBColor[0.941176, 0.972549, 1.], RGBColor[0.980392, 0.921569, 0.843137],
    RGBColor[0, 1., 1.], RGBColor[0.498039, 1., 0.831373],
    RGBColor[0.941176, 1., 1.], RGBColor[0.960784, 0.960784, 0.862745],
    RGBColor[1., 0.894118, 0.768627]}

colorToHex /@ colRGB
   {"#f0f8ff", "#faebd7", "#00ffff", "#7fffd4", "#f0ffff", "#f5f5dc", "#ffe4c4"}
```

Compare with the values listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp).

Comment: Thank you for `colorToHex`.

Answer (score 5):

`Hue[x]` is equivalent to `Hue[x, 1, 1]`. You can create a simple "table" of colors mapped to `x` as:

```
Graphics[{Hue@#, Disk[], Text[Style[ToString@#, FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 15]]}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 1, 0.1] // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

If you want the RGB values, use `ColorConvert`.

Comment: The circles represent all the colors used in the plot into my question, right? So, how can i convert the circles in RGB or HTML values like `149,56,56` or `953838`.

Comment: @FormlessCloud Use `ColorConvert`, as I said. See Sjoerd's answer for an example.

Answer (score 4):

```
ColorConvert[Hue[0.1], "RGB"]
```

> RGBColor[1., 0.6, 0.]

All hues, graphically:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[ColorConvert[Hue[h], "RGB"] /. RGBColor -> List, {h, 0, 1, 0.01}]\[Transpose], 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Would `ColorData["HTML"]` solve your problem? There are 140 colors in that list.

```
ColorData["HTML", "ColorRules"] // Take[#, 5] & // Column
```

> ```
> AliceBlue->RGBColor[0.941176,0.972549,1.]
> AntiqueWhite->RGBColor[0.980392,0.921569,0.843137]
> Aqua->RGBColor[0,1.,1.]
> Aquamarine->RGBColor[0.498039,1.,0.831373]
> Azure->RGBColor[0.941176,1.,1.]
> ```

```
Plot3D[Cos[2 x - y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .1},
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#1] &)]
```

[image: plot1]

You can color your plot instead of `Hue[#1]` where `#1` is x-coordinate rescaled to interval [0, 1] with the closest RGB color in `ColorData["HTML"]`.

```
With[{nf = Nearest[
    List @@@ ColorData["HTML", "ColorList"]]},
 Plot3D[Cos[2 x - y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .1},
  ColorFunction -> (Apply[RGBColor,
      nf[ColorConvert[Hue[#1], "RGBColor"]][[1]]] &)]]
```

[image: plot2]

It looks the same!? It does, but it's colored with those 140 colors. See:

```
With[{nf = Nearest[
    List @@@ ColorData["GeologicAges", "ColorList"]]},
 Plot3D[Cos[2 x - y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .1},
  ColorFunction -> (Apply[RGBColor,
      nf[ColorConvert[Hue[#1], "RGBColor"]][[1]]] &)]]
```

[image: plot3]

You may find `ColorData["HTML"]` useful as well (with 216 distinct shades).

```
ColorData["WebSafe", "Image"]
```

[image: colors]

Their name is their hex code:

```
ColorData["WebSafe", "ColorRules"] // Take[#, 7] & // Column
```

> ```
> #FFFFFF->RGBColor[1.,1.,1.]
> #FFFFCC->RGBColor[1.,1.,0.8]
> #FFFF99->RGBColor[1.,1.,0.6]
> #FFFF66->RGBColor[1.,1.,0.4]
> #FFFF33->RGBColor[1.,1.,0.2]
> #FFFF00->RGBColor[1.,1.,0.]
> #FFCCFF->RGBColor[1.,0.8,1.]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

With newer Mathematica there new function for the task.

From ColorData get "HTML" as the desired scheme. 
Then use [`ImageRecolor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageRecolor.html) to exchange the [`Hue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hue.html). The need for an appropriate replacement from `Hue` to `RGBColor` is easier now.

With `ColorConvert` this can be done in one single built-in.

Export allows for detailed settings for web optimization for each jpg, png, gif, TIFF. These formats can be checked after reimport by explorative built-ins for example with [`ImageColorSpace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageColorSpace.html).