# How to get hex color code from the image

Tags: color, image

I want to build a function which will work like this website: http://imagecolorpicker.com/

I'll upload the picture and get the hex or RGB color code of the color on the image, how is it possible?

For example I have [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dApi1.png) I know, it's hex code is #FF5733, how can I make Mathmatica define color for me?

Comment: If Mathmatica doesn't work with Hex colors, can I do same stuff with RGB colors?

Comment: What that site does correspond to `PixelValue[image, pos]` in wolfram

Comment: Note that if you load an image into *Mathematica* and then right-click on it, you'll see "Get Pixel Color" among the options.

Answer (score 4):

Import image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/dApi1.png"]
```

Assuming all pixels are the same, grab the RGB data from the first one:

```
id = ImageData[img][[1, 1]]*255
```

Hexify:

```
StringJoin["#", 
 StringPadLeft[IntegerString[Round[id], 16], 2, "0"]]
```

> `"#ff5733"`

Wrap it in a function (this time finding "commonest" pixel)...

```
gethex[img_?ImageQ] := 
 Module[{id = Round[Commonest[Join @@ ImageData[img]][[1]]*255]},
  StringJoin["#", StringPadLeft[IntegerString[Round[id], 16], 2, "0"]]
 ]
```

Comment: Another RGB -> hex converter can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13230).

Comment: @J.M. And a much more elegant and unrushed version as well...

Comment: Can I get RGB data automatically from the image by using Mathmatica?

Comment: @ArtemAnisimov, that's what the second step (`id`) does above.