# Obtain hexadecimal (html) color code from swatch?

Tags: color

Given a color swatch.

[image]

> How would I compute the corresponding hexadecimal triplet representation?

For instance: In the case of `Magenta` it is `"#ff00ff"`

## Question

> write a function that takes as input a swatch and returns the appropriate `(#RRGGBB)` string.

In the case of `Magenta` it should look like so:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13230)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two functions in the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository) to convert back and forth between a color and its hexadecimal representation.

[`HexToColor`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HexToColor) converts a hexadecimal string into a color.

[`ColorToHex`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ColorToHex/) converts a color to a hexadecimal string.

The swatch is simply how Mathematica visualizes `RGBColor` expressions so no extra step has to be taken to make it compatible with that. Example:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

The `ColorToHex` function show by C.E. is probably the easiest and best way for most people. If you wanted to write your own, something like this might be a start:

```
swatchToHex[swatch_] := 
 StringJoin["#", IntegerString[Round[255 Level[swatch, 1]], 16, 2]]
```

Here I'm using `Level` to extract the arguments, multiplying by 255 and rounding the result to the nearest integer, and then using `IntegerString` to display the numbers in base 16 with 2 digits shown.

I think this should work for any `RGBColor` swatch. However, some colours like `Black`, `Gray`, and `White` actually use `GrayLevel` with a single argument, and it's also possible to have `GrayLevel` with 2 arguments. To account for those, I can check the length of the arguments. If it's less than 3, I left pad the list with 2 more copies of the first argument. I'm also converting the colour to RGB first.

```
swatchToHex[swatch_] := StringJoin["#",
  IntegerString[Round[255 
    If[
      Length[#] < 3, 
      ArrayPad[#, {2, 0}, "Fixed"], 
      #
    ] &@ Level[ColorConvert[swatch, "RGB", 1]], 
  16, 
  2]
]
```

There might be some edge cases I'm not thinking of at the moment, but I think this should cover all of the cases.